# Custom Group and Fields using API v3

Tags: api, custom-fields

I'm trying to query the API on CiviCRM 4.4.6 for a Custom Field (Attachment) on a Case and an Activity.

I've tried the examples here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+Custom+Data+with+the+API
but couldn't get it to work.

I can see the custom fields available here;
SELECT * FROM `civicrm_value_attachments_52`

I can also see the entity_type for the case and file ID here:
SELECT * FROM `civicrm_entity_file`

What query do I write to extract the attachment for a case or activity?

Comment: could you publish the api calls you tried, it should be fairly normal calls using the customvalue api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using the latest version of the [API explorer](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#explorer) to give you an idea of the API call. In general, if the custom field is attached to that entity you can just get it using the custom field number. The custom field number is the ID of the field, eg:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Case', 'get', array(
'sequential' => 1,
'return' => "custom_315",
'id' => 1,
));
```

or REST:

```
/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Case&action=get&api_key=yourkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"return":"custom_13","id":1}
```

Comment: One way with no results:

/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=CustomValue&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&entity_id=533&return.civicrm_value_attachments_52:file_upload_1_316=1&entity_id=533

{
 "is_error":0,
 "undefined_fields":["return_civicrm_value_attachments_52:file_upload_1_316"],
 "version":3,
 "count":0,
 "values":[],
 "xdebug":{
  "peakMemory":41865784,
  "memory":41708336,
  "timeIndex":0.706025123596
 }
}

Tried this, but data not present in response:
/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Case&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&id=533&return=file_upload_1_316

No luck.

Comment: Also tried (with and without custom_)

`code`
/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Case&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&id=533&return=custom_file_upload_1_316
`code`

with no luck and 

`code`
/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Case&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&id=533&return.custom_file_upload_1_316=1
`code`

Comment: Thanks @john. Still no results using your method with: /civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Case&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&id=533&return.custom_315=1 or /civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Case&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&id=533&return=custom_315

Comment: Using the API docs explorer, it seems the field names are accurate: custom_316 File Upload 1 Case::Attachments File
custom_317 File Upload 2 Case::Attachments File
custom_318 File Upload 3 Case::Attachments File
custom_319 File Upload 4 Case::Attachments File

Comment: The following seems to return the file ID as 'latest'

/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=CustomValue&action=get&debug=1&sequential=1&json=1&return.custom_316=1&entity_id=533

{
 "is_error":0,
 "undefined_fields":["return_custom_316"],
 "version":3,
 "count":1,
 "id":316,
 "values":[{
  "entity_id":"533",
  "latest":"39",
  "id":"316",
  "0":"39"
 }],
 "xdebug":{
  "peakMemory":41831656,
  "memory":41690848,
  "timeIndex":0.714242935181
 }
}

I guess I'll have to use the ID to perform another query on the file itself using the ID. I would chain, but the explorer in this CiviCRM isn't up to the latest.

Comment: I've added the syntax for the REST call to the answer, see if that works for you?